# How to run a JS Function in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

How can I run my function "title()" in HTML?
I have created a "main.js" File, in there, there is following Code:

```
 "use strict";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    let newScript = document.createElement("script");
    newScript.src = "javascript/head.js";
    let heads = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    console.log(heads)
    heads.prepend(newScript);
});
```

in the "main.js" File load an another Script which is called "head.js" and here is the Code of this File:

```
function title(titleName) {
    let title = document.createElement("title");
    document.title = titleName;
    document.head.appendChild(title);
}
```

Maybye you need my HTML Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script> title("Framework"); </script>
</head>
<body>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would put `<script src="javascript/main.js"></script>` and  `<script> title("Framework"); </script>` at the bottom of your body tag ..  So the DOM is loaded before the script.

Comment: why would you want to run the function?  It seems like you want a dynamic title - is there some code that is loading the page content that you could link to setting the title? It seems strange to do this the way you are.

Comment: To further what @nycynik is saying:  There is zero SEO benefit doing this ...  As most robots do not load JavaScript.  Try setting your title with a back-end language so that the HTML is rendered with a title intact.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in `head.js` add:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => title("my desired title name"));
```

Not sure why someone downvoted, but to clarify, you can run this code anywhere so long as the `head.js` file has been loaded, it doesn't have to be directly in `head.js`.

You can add it into `main.js`:

```
let newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.addEventListener("load", () => title("my desired title name"));
newScript.src = "javascript/head.js";
// ...
```

You can also run it directly in the HTML in a `<script>` tag but you'll have to ensure the script is loaded first.